# Print array without brackets and commas

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, collections

I'm porting a Hangman game to Android and have met a few problems. The original Java program used the console, so now I have to somehow beautify the output so that it fits my Android layout.

How do I print an array without the brackets and commas? The array contains slashes and gets replaced one-by-one when the correct letter is guessed.

I am using the usual `.toString()` function of the `ArrayList` class and my output is formatted like: `[ a, n, d, r, o, i, d ]`. I want it to simply print out the array as a single `String`.

I fill the array using this bit of code:

```
List<String> publicArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < secretWordLength; i++) {
    hiddenArray.add(secretWord.substring(i, i + 1));
    publicArray.add("-");
}
```

And I print it like this:

```
TextView currentWordView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentWord);
currentWordView.setText(publicArray.toString());
```

Comment: The toString() method on the List interface is really just meant for debugging and logging. You shouldn't use it to present output to the user.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Basically, don't use `ArrayList.toString()` - build the string up for yourself. For example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String value : publicArray) {
    builder.append(value);
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

(Personally I wouldn't call the variable `publicArray` when it's not actually an array, by the way.)

Answer (score 116):

Replace the brackets and commas with empty space.

```
String formattedString = myArrayList.toString()
    .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
    .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
    .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
    .trim();           //remove trailing spaces from partially initialized arrays
```

Comment: Just don't put elements containing brackets and commas in the list.

Answer (score 26):

For Android, you can use the `join` method from [`android.text.TextUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) class like:

```
TextUtils.join("",array);
```

Comment: TextUtils takes Iterable as well

Answer (score 19):

first

`StringUtils.join(array, "");`

second

`Arrays.asList(arr).toString().substring(1).replaceFirst("]", "").replace(", ", "")`

EDIT

probably the best one: `Arrays.toString(arr)`

Comment: As a bonus `StringUtils` doesnt require a string array, it will work on Integers, Doubles, Objects, etc.

Answer (score 14):

With Java 8 or newer, you can use `String.join`, which provides the same functionality:

> Returns a new String composed of copies of the CharSequence elements joined together with a copy of the specified delimiter

```
String[] array = new String[] { "a", "n", "d", "r", "o", "i", "d" };
String joined = String.join("", array); //returns "android"
```

With an array of a different type, one should convert it to a String array or to a char sequence Iterable:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

//both of the following return "1234567"
String joinedNumbers = String.join("",
        Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(n -> new String[n]));
String joinedNumbers2 = String.join("",
        Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The first argument to `String.join` is the delimiter, and can be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

If you use Java8 or above, you can use with stream() with native.

```
publicArray.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

## References

- [Use Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)
- [JavaDoc StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)
- [Joining Objects into a String with Java 8 Stream API](https://coderwall.com/p/im4lja/joining-objects-into-a-string-with-java-8-stream-api)

Answer (score 5):

the most simple solution for removing the brackets is,

1. convert the arraylist into string with .toString() method.
2. use String.substring(1,strLen-1).(where strLen is the length of string after conversion from arraylist).
3. the result string is your string with removed brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I have used 
Arrays.toString(array_name).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(", ","");
as I have seen it from some of the comments above, but also i added an additional space character after the comma (the part **.replace(", ","")**), because while I was printing out each value in a new line, there was still the **space character** shifting the words. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I used join()  function like:

```
i=new Array("Hi", "Hello", "Cheers", "Greetings");
i=i.join("");
```

Which Prints:
     `HiHelloCheersGreetings`

See more: [Javascript Join - Use Join to Make an Array into a String in Javascript](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Javascript_Join_-_Use_Join_to_Make_an_Array_into_a_String_in_Javascript.shtml)

Comment: The question is about Java

Comment: this does work in java.. ["this","stuff"].join(","); = "this,stuff"

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] students = {"John", "Kelly", "Leah"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students).replace("[", "").replace("]", " "));

//output: John, Kelly, Leah
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30746592)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce method provided for streams for Java 8 and above.Note you would have to map to string first to allow for concatenation inside of reduce operator.

```
publicArray.stream().map(String::valueOf).reduce((a, b) -> a + " " + b).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with ArrayList and I also wanted to remove the Square brackets after printing the Output and I found out a Solution. I just made a loop to print Array list and used the list method " myList.get(index) " , it works like a charm.

Please refer to my Code & Output below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Value " + i + " to add: ");
            mylist.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("=======================");

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(mylist.get(j));
        }
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Enter Value 0 to add:

1

Enter Value 1 to add:

2

Enter Value 2 to add:

3

Enter Value 3 to add:

4

Enter Value 4 to add:

5

=======================

12345

Answer (score -4):

Just initialize a `String` object with your array

```
String s=new String(array);
```