# print array of objects without brackets

Tags: java, arrays

How can i print an array from a 2d without brackets. Basically am adding first the array with the new values to a 2d with :

```
books=(Object[][]) Arrays.copyOf(row,2);
```

whereas books is already initialized as 2d array with :

```
    static Object[][] books=new Object[1][1];
```

BUT when I try to print the first row from books with :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(books[0])+" ");
```

it prints me brackets and commas

```
[asds,asdas,223]
```

like is suppose to do.

How can i remove those?

Thank you !

Comment: Just loop through it yourself and build a String whichever way you want? Simple example: `String str = ""; for(int i = 0; i < books[0].length; i++) str += books[0][i] + " ";`.

Comment: I am not familiar with JAVA. I got thi s while searching. This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389480/print-array-without-brackets-and-commas

Comment: If you don't want the default formatting, you should iterate on your array and do the formatting yourself. To do so, follow @Lavekush's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
String output ;
    for(String s: books[0]){
      output = output +s+ ",";
    }
output = output.substring(0, output.length()-1);
System.out.print(output);
```

Comment: Depending on the number of items contained in the matrix, a `StringBuilder` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Undoubtedly, using `StringBuilder` will improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll` and simply:

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String value : publicArray) {

       builder.append(value +",");

       // or builder.append(value).append(",");
    }

    String text = builder.toString();
    System.out.print(text);
```

Comment: since you already have a `StringBuilder`, you should use `append()` a second time, instead of `+`. That would be `builder.append(value).append(",");`. This way, you avoid the implicit allocation of a new `StringBuilder`.