# How to remove the brackets [ ] from ArrayList#toString()?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an Array List in Java that looks something like this:

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> error = new ArrayList<>();

for (int x= 1; x<10; x++)
 { 
    errors.add(x);
 }
```

When I print errors I get it errors as

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Now I want to remove the **brackets([ ])** from this array list. I thought I could use the method errors.remove("["), but then I discovered that it is just boolean and displays a true or false. Could somebody suggest how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389480/print-array-without-brackets-and-commas

Comment: The boolean returned by list.remove() actually indicates if the value was found in the list or not. See the JavaDoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably calling [System.out.println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) to print the list. The JavaDoc says:

```
This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value
```

The brackets are added by the `toString` implementation of ArrayList. To remove them, you have to first get the String:

```
String errorDisplay = errors.toString();
```

and then strip the brackets, something like this:

```
errorDisplay = errorDisplay.substring(1, errorDisplay.length() - 1);
```

It is not good practice to depend on a `toString()` implementation. `toString()` is intended only to generate a human readable representation for logging or debugging purposes. So it is better to build the String yourself whilst iterating:

```
List<Integer> errors = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 1; x<10; x++) { 
    errors.add(x);
    sb.append(x).append(",");
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
String errorDisplay = sb.toString();
```

Note that this is not an array, just a String displaying the contents of the list. To create an array from a list you can use [list.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)):

```
// create a new array with the same size as the list
Integer[] errorsArray = new Integer[errors.size()];
// fill the array
errors.toArray(errorsArray );
```

EDIT: From an object-oriented perspective one could argue that errors and errorsDisplay conceptually belong together in a class, e.g:

```
public class Errors {

    private final List<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(int error) {
        codes.add(error);
    }

    public Stream<Integer> get() {
        return codes.stream();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return codes.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I actually want to access this array in a sepearte class. But I need it without the squared brackets since arrays cannot be declared with them.  But thank you for that detailed explanation :)

Comment: It's cleaner to create the array and pass it to that class than to create a String with comma's and do String.split() on it.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `System.out.println(errors.toString().substring(1, errors.toString().length() - 1))`

Explanation: when you call `System.out.println(obj)` with an `Object` as a parameter, the printed text will be the result of  `obj.toString()`. `ArrayList.toString()` is implemented in a way that makes it represent its content between brackets `[]` in a comma separated concatenation of each of the contained items (their `.toString()` representation as well).

It is not a good practice to rely on another class's `toString()` implementation. You should use your own way to format your result.

Comment: Your substring is faulty, since `errors.length` does not account for the comma separators. Also `length` is a field, not a method.

Comment: @Dragondraikk you are right, there was a `.toString()` missing :) *fixed*

Comment: it should be **erros.toString.length() - 1**

Comment: @dotvav : Thank you for that quick and detailed response. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

The brackets you see are just an automatic way to display a List in JAVA (when using `System.out.println(list);` for example.

If you do not want them to show when showing it, you can create a custom method :

```
public void showList(List<Integer> listInt)
{
    for(int el : listInt)
    {
        System.out.print(el + ", ");
    }
}
```

Then adjust this code to show this according to your liking !

Answer (score 2):

If you print your error list, it will internally call the `toString()` method of your list and this method add the brackets. There are a few possibilities. You can get the String via `toString()` method an remove the brackets from the String. Or you write your own method to print the List.

```
public static <T> void printList(List<T> list)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(T element : list)
        output.append(element + ", ");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: I would even use StringBuilder and append() method, then return one String via `System.out.print();` to fasten up and optimize code :)

Answer (score 2):

The brackets are not actually within the list it's just a representation of the list. If any object goes into a String output the objects toString() method gets called. In case of ArrayList this method delivers the content of the list wrapped by this brackets.

If you want to print your ArrayList without brackets just iterate over it and print it.

Answer (score 2):

There are not brackets inside your list.
This is just the way Java prints a list by default.

If you want to print the content of your list, you can something like this

```
for (Integer error : errors) {
    System.out.format("%d ", error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = errors.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");//remove brackets([) convert it to string
```

Comment: If in-between array as value then it would be not possible?

Answer (score 1):

brackets is not a part of your array list, since as you've mentioned it's Integer typed

> `ArrayList<Integer>`

when you print errors using

```
System.out.println(errors);
```

it's just formatting your data, just iterate over the array and print each value separately

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(error.toString().substring(1, error.toString().length()-1));`
This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use `String.join` method like below.

```
String.join(",",errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an `ArrayList` of `Integer`. This `ArrayList` can not contain a character like `'['`.  But you can remove an `Integer` from it like this -

```
error.remove(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this.

`String output = errors.toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove all the brackets using replaceAll() method like this:-
`System.out.println(errors.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with ArrayList and I also wanted to remove the Square brackets after printing the Output and I found out a Solution. I just made a loop to print Array list and used the list method " myList.get(index) " , it works like a charm.

Please refer to my Code & Output below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Value " + i + " to add: ");
            mylist.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("=======================");

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(mylist.get(j));
        }
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Enter Value 0 to add:

1

Enter Value 1 to add:

2

Enter Value 2 to add:

3

Enter Value 3 to add:

4

Enter Value 4 to add:

5

=======================

12345