# How to convert list to string in Groovy and remove brackets without using replace?

Tags: string, groovy

So I have the following code where I add some elements to a list, sort them and print as a string..

```
 def officeWorkers = []
 officeWorkers << "Jim Halpert"
 officeWorkers << "Dwight Shrute"
 officeWorkers << "Toby Flenderson"
 officeWorkers.sort()
 println("I wish my co workers were ${officeWorkers.toString()}")
```

The resulting string has opening and closing brackets ('[', ']') which I don't want ("I wish my co workers were [Dwight Shrute, Jim Halpert, Toby Flenderson]").

It seems one way to remove those brackets is to use String's replace function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389480/print-array-without-brackets-and-commas).

But what if in the actual list I am using there are already brackets in the values, they would get replaced also.

So is there a way to print out this list as a string without having those brackets show up and without using the replace function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use join:

```
println("I wish my co workers were ${officeWorkers.join(', ')}")
```

Comment: but what if you don't want the spaces?

Comment: Don't add them... 