# Array data is shown with square brackets when parsing data from a JSON file using Gson in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I am creating an Android application. I have saved all data in a JSON file. I'm trying to parse a JSON array in Android. The problem is I am getting the JSON array data with the enclosed square brackets. I'm using Gson to parse the data.

My json file format is like this:

```
   [
     {
      id:"",
      contents:
      {
       tips:
        [
         "get signed in",
         "create a channel"
        ]
      }
     }
   ]
```

The JSON array data is stored in a text view "tips".

```java
   TextView tips = ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tips));
   tips.setText(mMethod.contents.tips.toString());
```

But I am getting the output like this:

> **[get signed in create a channel]**

This is how I parse my JSON

```
try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show the code where you parse the json

Comment: Almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389480/print-array-without-brackets-and-commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your printing an array. Thats the reason your getting the square brackets.

You might want to print it out like.

```
for(String s:mMethod.contents.tips){
  tips.append(s);
}
```